# ELB health checks failing only for HTTPS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am currently running a ELB (application type) on my Ubuntu single instance, it is set up to listen to HTTP and HTTPS. The HTTP target group health check is fine, however, the HTTPS target group health check is not. And unfortunately, the tooltip does not provide much help by returning me a message of "Health checks failed".

So when i try and access my site via a domain on the HTTPS protocol, it is returning me a 502 bad gateway error. However, accessing the site on the HTTP protocol works fine. At the moment, the domain is pointing to my ELB.

So far, i have tried the following but still have yet to solve this issue.

1) I have ensured the security group for the ELB and my Ubuntu instance accepts inbound traffic from HTTP and HTTPS as well as outbound traffic of all available ports.

2) I have added a ACM cert to the ELB HTTPS listener and it is forwarding it to a target group that sits on the HTTPS protocol.

3) Added a virtualhost 443 entry on apache2 conf file, similar to that of the port 80.

Is there a way for me to debug why the HTTPS target group health checks are failing? Or am i missing something here.

Comment: It sounds like the port 443 target group is configured for HTTPS, which is not what you want unless you have SSL certs on the instances themselves.  You only want the ALB *listener* configured for HTTPS, not the target.  Check that?

Comment: Hi Michael, i just tried your suggestion and it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sqlbot I cannot express my gratitude for your comment. Hours wasted on this.